Fresh rocky9 install causing PCI bus errors?
Im in the process of upgrading machines from CentOS7 -> Rocky9. Ive done a few dozen successfully but have run into a problem with newer Dell R440.
When the new OS boots I get an error in DRAC A fatal error was detected on a component at bus 2 device 0 function 0.
I've tried replacing the main board but the problem persists.
Is this even possible? (for an OS to cause a (possible) hardware error) ?
-- edit
I was able to reproduce this on multiple R440s

The workaround/solution for this is published by Red Hat: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7062084
You can downgrade to kernel 5.14.0-284.11.1.el9_2
Or you can add the following parameter to the kernel boot line (assuming kernel-5.14.0-427.18.1.el9_4.x86_64 or newer): printk_no_perconsole_kthreads



